# Select element inside parent div

Tags: jquery, css

I need to select element that I think can be selected with this code:

```
#main_slider h2 < img#main_slider_menu_image {
    background: initial !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    width: 90% !important;
}
```

I'm trying to select #main_slider h2 that have image with id #main_slider_menu_image. I really need make it work. But this code is not working now. So have can I write it true to make this work?

Also add full html block:

```
<div class="main" id="main_slider">
    <h2>Фланцевые уплотнения</h2>
    <img id="main_slider_menu_image" class="slider_img" src="/upload/iblock/360/ngzzkvgrvbicbboyyo thkgszaddkxcakjzktvq.png">
    <p>
        Прокладки стальные овального и восьмиугольного сечения, уплотнительные линзы. Прокладки паронитовые, фторопластовые, безасбестовые, прокладки из терморасширенного графита. Прокладки спирально-навитые.
    </p>
</div>
```

Jquery added now as tag, because no way to do it by CSS. Still loking answer. 
I have selected p by using:

```
img#main_slider_menu_image ~ p  { 

 }
```

because p is after img, but I can't select h2 this way because it before img. 
Image switch classes in slider and I have task to change style of h2, And all I have is only image with different classes.

and when list hovered image switch id to main_slider_menu_image
. Very difficult task for me, and I son't know the programmer who made this slider...
The website is [Bitrix website](http://new.myrussiaonline.com/) [image: Image to understand what I need]

Comment: The "parent selector" doesn't exist in CSS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: See my answer, with adjacent sibling selector (`+`)

Answer (score 1):

That's `<` doesn't exists in CSS. There will be the opposite:

```
#main_slider h2 > img#main_slider_menu_image
```

See more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

In your case, your solution is the sibling selector

```
#main_slider h2 + img#main_slider_menu_image
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: #main_slider h2 + img#main_slider_menu_image  have tried this code, but this select image instead of h2

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that you need to select `h2`. Unfortunately this doesn't exists in CSS, so you need to try with a javascript/jquery solution. See the @RiccardoC answer. Good luck.

Comment: Thank's you. Now I know that I need to use jQuery) Because I'm bad with JS:)